# How to get the element from the other list, according to the values in the current list?

Tags: python

I have one list that keep the sequence of number like.

```
a_list = [1,1,0,1,0,1]
```

I have two options that I have an idea for.

1. I have another list that keep the number of elements to get from a_list like:

```
b = [[1,1,4]]
```

The output will be like this:

```
output: [[[1],[1],[0,1,0,1]]]
```

Or the other option.

2. I have another list that keep the positions that I want the others to get from that position up to that position like.

```
c = [[0,1,4]]
```

And, the output will be like this:

```
output: [[[1],[1],[0,1,0,1]]]
```

My Code is:

```
def split(the_list, combi_list):
    j = 0
    result_list = []
    while j < len(combi_list):
        re2 = []
        for i in range(len(combi_list[j])):
            ft = combi_list[j][i]
            re2.append(the_list[:ft])
        result_list.append(re2)
        j += 1
    del the_list[:ft]
    return result_list
```

In the function `split` I pass `a_list` in `the_list` and `b` or `c` in `combi_list`

And I get this result:

For first option:

```
Input: [[1,1,4],[1,2,3]]
output: [[[1], [1], [1, 1, 0, 1]], [[0], [0, 1], [0, 1]]]
```

For second option:

```
Input: [[0,1,4],[0,1,3]]
output: [[[], [1], [1, 1, 0, 1]], [[], [0], [0, 1]]]
```

(Both of them also pass `a_list` as an arguments)
What options should I choose? Can u help me to correct my code? Thank you So Much!!!!

Comment: Why are you deleting from `the_list` at the end?

Comment: I'd consider making the `b` list, which drives the retrieval of elements of interest, from tuples of parameters that you can use with [slice](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=slice#slice) (start, stop, and optionally step). That way you have flexibility to take overlapping regions and skip regions entirely, as needed.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a simple generator function:

```
a_list = [1,1,0,1,0,1]
b = [1,1,4]

def split(input, counts):
  start = 0
  for count in counts:
    yield input[start:start+count]
    start += count 

print(list(split(a_list, b)))
```

Prints

```
[[1], [1], [0, 1, 0, 1]]
```

Comment: That's not the desired output. It's missing a level of nesting.

Comment: @Barmar Im showing how the logic works not a 1:1 solution...

Answer (score 0):

You can look into using a copy of the list and the .pop() command to treat the list like a stack. Read the first element of the list for however many items you want to retrieve.

Answer (score 0):

```
from itertools import islice

a_list = [1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1]
a_list_iter = iter(a_list)

lengths = [1, 1, 4]

print([list(islice(a_list_iter, length)) for length in lengths])
```

Output:

```
[[1], [1], [0, 1, 0, 1]]
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use for loop to iterate from one list and use the index of one to get in other place.
for eg:

```
lst1 = [1,2,3,5,9]         #the list which have index
lst2 = list(range(2,20,2)) #The other list who's values are needed to pull
new_lst = list()
for items in lst1:
    new_lst.append(lst2[items])
#voila you got your list.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use list comprehensions:

```
[ [a_list[:p] for p in pos] for pos in b ]
```